# Unsupported url in JSONP request

Tags: json, url, extjs, jsonp

My web app loads from localhost/alpha/ and
I get the following error message from the browser (Chrome or Safari) when it performs a JSONP request :

```
GET localhost:5000/ISeeYou/webservice/login.php?email=b&pwd=b&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1&_dc=1377281924940 unsupported URL
```

I am using Sencha Touch and this is my code :

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                        url: ISeeYou.url+'/ISeeYou/webservice/login.php',
                        params:{
                            email: email,
                            pwd: pwd
                        },
                        success: function(response){}
});
```

When I copy/paste the url that is displayed in the error directly in the browser it works very well.

Comment: Are you using a library to perform the JSONP call? My guess is it doesn't like `.` in the callback function.

Comment: I am using Sencha Touch to perform the request and the problem doesn't seem to come from the `.`

Comment: Sencha Touch is hardware, I'm asking about the software. Please show your code.

Comment: Code added in the question

Comment: The answer to my first question is that you're using the Ext JS framework. I've updated the tags, maybe someone familiar with it will see the question now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It just needed "http://" at the beginning.